# Having to use provide() for each service in RC4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have the following bootstrapping code running fine in Beta:

```
bootstrap(App, [
    provide(Http, {
        useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions, helperService: HelperService, authProvider: AuthProvider) => new CustomHttp(backend, defaultOptions, helperService, authProvider),
        deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions, HelperService, AuthProvider]
    }),
    provide(LocationStrategy, { useClass: HashLocationStrategy }),
    provide("AppContext", { useValue: appContext }),
    provide("ClientService", { useValue: clientService }),
    AgendaService,
    ConfirmationService,
    HelperService
]).then((success: any) => {
        console.log("Bootstrap successful");
    }, (error: any) => console.error(error));
```

But now when updating to RC4, I have to change to following:

```
bootstrap(App, [
    provide(Http, {
        useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions, helperService: HelperService, authProvider: AuthProvider) => new CustomHttp(backend, defaultOptions, helperService, authProvider),
        deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions, HelperService, AuthProvider]
    }),
    provide(LocationStrategy, { useClass: HashLocationStrategy }),
    provide("AppContext", { useValue: appContext }),
    provide("ClientService", { useValue: clientService }),
    provide("AgendaService", { useClass: AgendaService }),
    provide("ConfirmationService", { useClass: ConfirmationService }),
    provide("HelperService", { useClass: HelperService })
]).then((success: any) => {
        console.log("Bootstrap successful");
    }, (error: any) => console.error(error));
```

So, I have to use `provide()` for each of my services and use `Inject()` in the components where these services are being injected otherwise, they cannot be injected and I get `NoProviderError` with message `No provider for xxx.service`. Is this expected or am I doing something wrong?

---

What seems to work is following:

```
bootstrap(App, [
    // provide(Http, {
    //     useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions, helperService: HelperService, authProvider: AuthProvider) => new CustomHttp(backend, defaultOptions, helperService, authProvider),
    //     deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions, HelperService, AuthProvider]
    // }),
    { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy },
    { provide: "AppContext", useValue: appContext },
    { provide: "ClientService", useValue: clientService },
    { provide: "AgendaService" useClass: AgendaService },
    { provide: "ConfirmationService" useClass: ConfirmationService },
    { provide: "HelperService" useClass: HelperService }
]).then((success: any) => {
        console.log("Bootstrap successful");
    }, (error: any) => console.error(error));
```

then everywhere these services are required `@Inject` has to be used:

`constructor(@Inject("HelperService") private helperService: HelperService){
}`

Anything else is giving of errors as before.

NOTE: I am using `useValue` instead of `useClass` for some services because I am manually instantiating those services based on certain conditions and its done before bootstrapping Angular, right above `bootstrap()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`provide()` (and also `new Provider()`)` is deprecated and was already removed in RC.6

The simplest way is just

```
AgendaService
```

which is the short form of

```
{provide: AgendaService, useClass: AgendaService}
```

If the key and the value differ, then you **need** to use this long form, if not, then prefer the short form because it's much easier to read.

Here the long form is required because key `LocatonStrategy` is different than the value `HashLocationStrategy`:

```
{ provide: LocationStrategy,  useClass: HashLocationStrategy }),
```

Comment: If I use the short form then I get the following error message `Uncaught Cannot resolve all parameters for 'AgendaService'(@Inject(GraphApiService), AppContext @Inject(AppContext), @Inject(ClientService), undefined, undefined, undefined). Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations and that 'AgendaService' is decorated with Injectable.`

Comment: This is the constructor of `AgendaService`: `constructor( @Inject("GraphApiService") private graphService: IApiService,
        @Inject("AppContext") private context: AppContext,
        @Inject("ClientService") private clientService: IClientService,
        private figgApiService: FiggApiService,
        private helperService: HelperService,
        private loaderService: InfiniteLoaderService) {
    }`

Comment: Can't imagine this to be different if you use the long form. Actually if you provide it with `useValue: AngendaService` instead of `useClass: AgendaService` then DI passes the **Agenda class** **not an instance** of it. This is why you don't get an error. You need to ensure the dependencies of `AngendaService` are properly provided and have an `@Injectable()` decorator.

Comment: Get rid of these `@Inject("GraphApiService")` decorators form the constructor parameters and use the forms I showed in my answer. Then please update your question to show the updated code and the error messages you with it.

Comment: This the new error I get: `Uncaught Cannot resolve all parameters for 'AgendaService'(?, AppContext, ?, undefined, undefined, undefined). Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations and that 'AgendaService' is decorated with Injectable.`. Updated the question.

Comment: Why do keep providing classes with `useValue` (according to your updated question)? It should be `useClass` if you want Angular2 DI to pass you an instance.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding I will update the question with the preceding code. Did not want to add more code to make the question more ambiguous.

Comment: Remove the quotes in `provide: "AppContext",` and the `@Inject("...")` decorators from constructor parameters. Where `provide` and `useClass:` is the same change it to class-only - example: change `{ provide: "AgendaService" useClass: AgendaService },` to `AgandaService`

Comment: `{ provide: "AppContext", useValue: appContext },` can be changed to `{ provide: AppContext, useValue: appContext },` and then also for `constructor private appContext:AppContext) {}` the `@Inject("AppContext")` decorator can be removed.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use `provide` for each of your service. also `provide` from `@angular/core` is deprecated so you need to use provider as below :

```
bootstrap(App, [
    {
      provide : Http,
      useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions, helperService: HelperService, authProvider: AuthProvider) => new CustomHttp(backend, defaultOptions, helperService, authProvider),
      deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions, HelperService, AuthProvider]
    },
    {
      provide : LocationStrategy,
      useClass: HashLocationStrategy
    },
    {
      provide : AppContext,
      useValue: appContext
    },
    {
      provide : ClientService,
      useValue: clientService
    },
    AgendaService,
    ConfirmationService,
    HelperService
]).then((success: any) => {
        console.log("Bootstrap successful");
    }, (error: any) => console.error(error));
```

also make sure that you have added `@Injectable()` for your AgendaService,  ConfirmationService and HelperService.

For example for AgendaService its as below :

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class AgendaService {
}
```